# How to turn column headers into row in order to plot in chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, charts

This is what happens when I try df.T.plot and it is pulling from the wrong dataframe:

[image]

```
df1 = open_res[['Name','6-Jun','16-Jun','26-Jun','6-Jul','16-Jul','26-Jul','5-Aug','15-Aug','4-Sep','14-Sep','24-Sep','30-Aug','4-Oct','14-Sep','24-Oct','3-Nov','13-Nov','23-Nov','3-Dec']]
df2 = df1.loc[df1['Name'] == 'Global']
df2
```

The data returns show each date in the format seen above as a column head. How can I change it so that they may be plotted along the x axis?

The data as seen in the picture is cleaned up because I just want the Global row

[image]

Comment: Use `df.T.plot()` transpose the dataframe making coluwns into rows, the plot.

Comment: When I run that with the correlating data frame it says "TypeError: no numeric data to plot"

Answer (score 0):

You get that error the first column is a string and your other columns are numeric, and when you transpose, everything is converted to string. Using some example data like yours:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

open_res = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(2,19)),
                        columns=['6-Jun','16-Jun','26-Jun','6-Jul','16-Jul','26-Jul','5-Aug','15-Aug',
                                '4-Sep','14-Sep','24-Sep','30-Aug','4-Oct','14-Sep','24-Oct',
                                 '3-Nov','13-Nov','23-Nov','3-Dec'])
open_res['Name'] = ['Global','x']
df1 = open_res[['Name','6-Jun','16-Jun','26-Jun','6-Jul','16-Jul','26-Jul','5-Aug','15-Aug',
                '4-Sep','14-Sep','24-Sep','30-Aug','4-Oct','14-Sep','24-Oct','3-Nov','13-Nov','23-Nov','3-Dec']]
df2 = df1.loc[df1['Name'] == 'Global']
```

We transpose:

```
df2.T.dtypes
0    object
```

You can do:

```
df2.set_index('Name').T.plot()
```

[image]